# Real part of X(jw)=even part of x(t)?

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $x(t) \stackrel{F}{\longleftrightarrow}X(j\omega)$ be a Fourier transform pair. Is it true that the real part of $X(j\omega)$ equals the even part of $x(t)$?

If it is true, then does the imaginary part of $X(j\omega)$ equal the odd part of $x(t)$?

I'm in a EE class that used the first of these identities in a problem I found the solution to online. The problem was 4.25 f from Signals and Systems by Oppenheim and Willsky, ed. 2. I can't find this anywhere. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Defining the Fourier transform as
$$X(j \omega) = \mathcal{F}\left[x(t)\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega t} x(t) \mathrm{d} t$$
and the composition of $x$ into even and odd parts as
$$ x(t) = x_{even}(t) + x_{odd}(t) = \frac{x(-t) + x(t)}{2} + \frac{x(-t) - x(t)}{2}$$
one can write the transform as
$$ X(j \omega) = \mathcal{F}\left[x_{even}(t) + x_{odd}(t)\right]
= \mathcal{F}\left[x_{even}(t)\right] + \mathcal{F}\left[x_{odd}(t)\right] \mathrm{.}$$

Generally for the complex conjugate of a Fourier transform holds
$$\overline{X(j \omega)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{e^{-j \omega t}} x(t) \mathrm{d} t = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{j \omega t} x(t) \mathrm{d} t = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega \tau} x(-\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau $$
and if $x(t)$ is even ($x(\tau) = x(-\tau)$)
$$\overline{X(j \omega)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega \tau} x(-\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega \tau} x(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = X(j \omega) $$
so $X(j \omega)$ is real. Equivalently for odd $x$
$$\overline{X(j \omega)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega \tau} x(-\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-j \omega \tau} x(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = - X(j\omega) $$
so $X(j \omega)$ is purely imaginary.

Therefore
$$ X(j \omega) = \mathcal{F}\left[x_{even}(t)\right] + \mathcal{F}\left[x_{odd}(t)\right] $$
where $$\mathcal{F}\left[x_{even}(t)\right] = \mathrm{Re}\left[ X(j\omega) \right]$$
and $$\mathcal{F}\left[x_{odd}(t)\right] = \mathrm{Im}\left[ X(j\omega) \right] \mathrm{.}$$